# Color Picker and Widget

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Now, I am working about color picker and widget in Wordpress. After I choose the color and submit it. My color picker is changed to text box. How can I solve this problem?

My code is below.

In form function:

```
   $instance            = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, array('background_color' => '#e3e3e3' ) ); 
$background_color   = isset( $instance['background_color'] ) ? esc_attr( $instance['background_color'] ) : ''; 

<label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'background_color' ); ?>" style="display:block;"><?php _e( 'Title Background Color:' ); ?></label> 
<input class="widefat color" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'background_color' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'background_color' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $background_color ); ?>" />
<div class="colorpicker"></div>
```

My js file.

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function(){

"use strict";

//This if statement checks if the color picker widget exists within jQuery UI
//If it does exist then we initialize the WordPress color picker on our text input field

if( typeof jQuery.wp === 'object' && typeof jQuery.wp.wpColorPicker === 'function' ){
    jQuery( '.color' ).wpColorPicker();
}

else {
    //We use farbtastic if the WordPress color picker widget doesn't exist
    jQuery( '.colorpicker' ).farbtastic( '.color' );
}
});
```

In function update

```
$instance['background_color']   = $new_instance['background_color'];
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution. Change js file as below.

```
//Set up the color pickers to work with our text input field
jQuery( document ).ajaxComplete(function(){

"use strict";

//This if statement checks if the color picker widget exists within jQuery UI
//If it does exist then we initialize the WordPress color picker on our text input field

if( typeof jQuery.wp === 'object' && typeof jQuery.wp.wpColorPicker === 'function' ){
    jQuery( '.color' ).wpColorPicker();
}

else {
    //We use farbtastic if the WordPress color picker widget doesn't exist
    jQuery( '.colorpicker' ).farbtastic( '.color' );
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for above answer. It'wrong, when I create new widget, it will show two color-picker.

Now, I fix this problem with this solution. (From Oren comment, http://zourbuth.com/archives/877/how-to-use-wp-color-picker-in-widgets/ )

```
jQuery(document).ready( function() {
jQuery('.color').wpColorPicker();
jQuery(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
jQuery('.color').wpColorPicker();
});
});
```